# Parallel processes Update Query in MySql

Tags: mysql

I check the result and if no rows were updated change the 5 to a 6 in this example and reissue the update query.
(The actual application is more complicated which requires this rather than simply setting to thecount + 1 without the where)

This example is simply trying to maintain a simple counter with multiple processes updating the counter.  I suspect that this is not working in my MySQL MyISAM table with counts getting missed.  Should I expect this to work for MyISAM and if not, should it work with INNODB?

UPDATE thetable SET thecount = thecount +1 WHERE thecount = 5;

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM has a really primitive concurrency system that requires locking the table during writes, so there's no risk of one query interfering with another like that. The downside is these writes will have to wait in line to be completed.

InnoDB has a better concurrency system and single statements like this are typically atomic, as per [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). It will work, and probably perform better.

Don't use MyISAM unless you have a very, very compelling reason. It's a very old engine that's not being updated by the MySQL team and is only provided for legacy support reasons.